# How can I use a list of integers as the input to a function of one integer and get a list as an output?

Tags: r, list, input

Apologies for asking a trivial question, but I'm stumped. Here's the situation:

- I have a function of three inputs `fishCounter(data, x, y)` where `data` is a matrix and both x and y are integers.
- `fishCounter` is in memory and works completely fine when I call it manually (e.g. `fishCounter(matrix(1:4,4,4), 1, 4)`). Its output is a single integer.
- The relevant data and value of x are in memory. x is simply 3, and we'll call the data  `trout`.
- I want R to spit out the list of results for every value of y from 1 to 20. Crudely, what I want is `fishCounter(trout, 3, 1:20)`.
- The way that R gives me this data (e.g. array, vector, list, etc) is not of interest, I just want the output however I can get it.
- Everything that I've tried to get this has failed. I could of course use a for loop and append this all to a vector, but that seems like far too much effort.
- My memory insists that there is a **very** simple way to get what I'm after. I'm sure that some version of `replicate`, `apply` or `lapply` will do this job.
- What I want is a single function that will give me this result. For example, I was surprised when `lapply(c(1:19), fishCounter(trout, 3, y)` didn't work.
- No libraries should be needed and I shouldn't need to code in any new functions. My memory insists that I'm either simply forgetting a function that's build in to R, have forgotten a term that would've got me the answer instantly from a search engine, or I've completely misunderstood the documentation on the three functions that I've listed earlier.

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `lapply` like below, i.e.,

```
lapply(1:20, function(y) fishCounter(trout, 3, y))
```

or `Vectorize` over your function `fishCounter`, i.e.,

```
Vectorize(fishCounter)(trout, 3, 1:20)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. What documentation should I have read to be able to figure that out?